# WPF DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames skipping frames

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am attempting to animate a slider using `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` and `DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame` to animate a slider for each key frame. However, it seems to be skipping frames when the storyboard is played, that is, the ValueChanged event is not firing for every key frame. The storyboard and animation are set up in the code-behind as follows:

```
DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames _timelineAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
Storyboard _timelineStoryboard = new Storyboard();

void SetupTimeline()
{
    // set up timeline storyboard animation
    _timelineAnimation.SpeedRatio = 1.0;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(_timelineAnimation, timelineSlider);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_timelineAnimation, new PropertyPath(Slider.ValueProperty));
    _timelineStoryboard.Children.Add(_timelineAnimation);
    timelineSlider.ValueChanged += TimelineSlider_ValueChanged;
}

void StartTimeline(List<double> times)
{
    foreach (double time in times)
    {
        double value = time - timelineSlider.Value;
        var keyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value));

        _timelineAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(time, keyTime));
    }

    _timelineStoryboard.Begin(timelineSlider, true);
}

// this does not fire for every key frame
void TimelineSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    Debug.Print($"TimelineSlider_ValueChanged {e.NewValue}");
}
```

Example input data (in seconds):

```
136.224
136.238 
136.244 
136.2441
136.246
136.2461
136.264 
136.274 
136.294 
136.2941
136.296 
136.2961
```

I imagine that the problem may be that the data items are too close together.  Is there any way to speed up the resolution of the animation timer? Or any other suggestions as to a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, when the interval between two frames is set below 30 milliseconds or so, some frames might be skipped.

This is much like a WPF `DispatcherTimer`. A WPF `DispatcherTimer`, no matter how small its [Interval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.interval?view=netframework-4.7.2) is, only ticks once in every (about) 30 milliseconds.

To produce animation effect, WPF uses a [time manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-and-timing-system-overview) to signal an update periodically. When it ticks, the animated properties (in this case, the `Value` property of the `Slider`) are re-evaluated and the UI is updated. And it apparently picks the “most recent” frame in the timeline and discard those are already outdated.

> The time manager "ticks" many times per second; the actual number of ticks that occur each second varies depending on available system resources.

Even if you manage to speed up the resolution timer - I guess it is not possible for a UI timer, say, make it tick every 1 millisecond, human eyes can't perceive such a high frequency in the animation, and, monitors display at only 50-60 Hz.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About what I expected to be the case. I was trying to use the animation to process a stream of varying events which drive a dashboard display through a slider that acts as a timeline. It is important that no events are dropped. I will have to use something like Reactive instead to drive the timeline.